# Find last action or action history in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

### Background

I was using the keyboard without paying much attention. Then I triggered something, then my selected code `top:0` becomes `<top:0></top:0>` I think this is useful for me but I don't know what key (was a 3-key-combo) I have pressed.

### Question

How to see action history like in Microsoft Office Word/Powerpint/Excel?

### I did ...

- Look up in user-defined key bindings.
- Searched possible extension settings.
- Searched VScode official documents.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that just by pressing `tab` or `enter` after typing what you want. What that key does is it selects the first available suggested action, and in this case it is the emmet abbreviation of "create HTML tag". You can see more information in the visual studio code documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) and the official emmet documentation [here](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/)

Also for your information, you can press `Ctrl + Shift + P` and then type `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting`. This will open your console and it will announce every key you press, the thing is this does not have any history of whatever you did prior to opening it so there is no way to view history.

Comment: Yes.. The thing was I dont remember pressing `tab` or `enter`. I believe I used the **Refactor** command (`Ctrl+Shift+R`). Then triggered something.
What I'm interested in (as specified in the `##Question` chapter) is how to check the history. M$ Office Word, Excel all has this function. I was expecting one but seems there's none? Also, please consider moving this part to the first paragraph as it is more related to the question.